# How to recover a SQL Server table after dropping and recreating it?

Tags: sql-server

I had a brainfart and accidentally dropped my table then recreated it. I hadn't realize it for a while until I checked and all my records were gone. The database was not backed up and it was on the server. I am not admin and not allowed to access.

Is there anything I can do to to recover that table? Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Version SQL Server 2017

Comment: Nope - when its gone it gone.

Comment: Well, I thought so but I'm really desperate right now

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** - we had 2012, 2014,2016, 2017 and will have 2019 sometime in the future - so which one are you talking about really??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this article help you to recover your data. But Your database must be in full recovery mode.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3160/recover-deleted-sql-server-data-and-tables-with-the-help-of-transaction-log-and-lsns/

Comment: as I said, my DB was not backed up so I cannot use this solution. And thank you.

Comment: Not talking about latest backup, last night full backup or last full backup. You can apply your transnational backup over that.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not technical: it's about the "what to do". (more of a "workplace relationship answer").
If you've done something bad (like this) own the mistake. Go to your boss and explain. Go to your DBA and ask for help. If you need to inform the business users that there was an error: please explain.
It happened to me once, telling the story to my friends had brought up many horror stories. Severe errors happen to many developers. Own the mistake, do your best to fix it and move on.

Comment: I did, and this is what I do to find a solution to fix it.